# how to resolve "Prop `id` did not match. Server: "react-tabs-30" Client: "react-tabs-0" console issue?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-tabs

i am trying tab in next in next.js, but every time i use it it show a console warning link this `` Prop `id` did not match. Server: "react-tabs-30" Client: "react-tabs-0" ``, i know it isn't effect my app but it is so annoying. how to solve this waring

```
<Tabs>
  <div className="tab-controler ml-sm-auto">
    <TabList className="tab-lists list-inline d-flex  flex-wrap nav mb-3" style={{ background: '#F8F8F8' }}>
      <Tab className={`${CostCalculatorStyle.PEItem} tab-lists__item`}>Buy & Ship for me</Tab>
      <Tab className={`${CostCalculatorStyle.PEItem} tab-lists__item`}>Ship for me</Tab>
    </TabList>
  </div>
  <TabPanel key={"tabpanel_ship"}>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-lg-6">
        <ShipForMeForm handleFormValue={handleFormValue} handleProductValue={handleProducts} handleRef={handleRef} />
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-6 align-self-center">
        <div className="costcalc-empty-thumb text-center">
          <Image
            src="/assets/topNavbarPages/costCalculator.svg"
            alt="Cost Calculator"
            width="469"
            height="288"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </TabPanel>
  <TabPanel key={"tabpanel_buy_ship"}>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-lg-6">
        <ShipForMeForm handleFormValue={handleFormValue} handleProductValue={handleProducts} handleRef={handleRef} />
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-6 align-self-center">
        <div className="costcalc-empty-thumb text-center">
          <Image
            src="/assets/topNavbarPages/costCalculator.svg"
            alt="Cost Calculator"
            width="469"
            height="288"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </TabPanel>
</Tabs>
```

as you can see i use `react-tabs` for tab but i also work on react js where i use the same code but it didn't show this console warning. so my question is why it is happing? and how i can solve it ?

Answer (score 16):

In next js i fixed it like that

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const Tabs = dynamic(import('react-tabs').then(mod => mod.Tabs), { ssr: false }) // disable ssr
import { Tab, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs'
```

it work for me

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I know of is just to set the `id` yourself in the `<Tabs>` component. Ex: `<Tabs id={1}>`

See https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/4328#issuecomment-890525420 for more details and examples.

Comment: In my situation, when I map the array and return the component, just put id prop solved the problem

```return (
<Checkbox
     id={item}
     inputRef={categoryRef}
     key={item}
rest of the code...```

Answer (score 3):

NextJs generating code in server side as you know.

This error means that something on the server is different from the Client. This can happen if the client does a re-render.

For example.

```
export default function Test(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <span>{props.name}</span>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have this simple `Test` component.And I send name **(1)** prop from another component to this `Test` component. And if I change this name **(to 2)** in client using redux (for example I have another name in my redux store) after page generated  I get this error.

> props did not match server "1" client "2"

To solve this error I need to just not change this name with redux after page generated in server. The data can be change only with user manipulations after page rendered in server.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me when I use **Tabs** from **react-bootstrap**. Koushik Saha's answer can be apply for that also but with a small change. Need to put `react-bootstrap` instead `react-tabs`

```
const Tabs = dynamic(import('react-bootstrap').then(mod => mod.Tabs), { ssr: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In case you miss it

If you are using Nextjs + Material-ui, there are actually custom codes that you can/need to include in your _`document.js` and `_app.js` to **remove the server-side injected CSS** so the CSS is recreated when page loads.

As codes changes with mui's and nextjs' version, i will refer you to the repository directly

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs/pages

Answer (score -1):

As per the documentation in the react-tabs repo/npmjs.org page ([https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tabs#resetidcounter-void)):

```js
import { resetIdCounter } from 'react-tabs';

resetIdCounter();

ReactDOMServer.renderToString(...);
```

I was having the same issue and called the `resetIdCounter` function inside my parent component to the tabs structure and cleared up the error.

Not sure if maybe there is a better place to use this function, like maybe in a `useEffect` hook or something, but I'm going with this for now.

Comment: Would be helpful if the person who gave this a -1 would explain why, to those who are still learning next.js.